# Crystal report Page Design issues

Tags: .net, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am trying to design a report in Crystal Reports as shown below.
[image]

I have been successful in designing most of the report, but it is not working once I place more data.

My Crystal Report currently prints:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that the labels are overlapping. I am not sure how to solve this one.

So basically I added two detail sections and a formula to suppress a section based on record numbers so that the records can be printed on an alternate location. But now the most obvious problem is that each section is taking its own height, but I have an overlapping print as shown in the above image.

If you have any ideas or suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it,

I created two sub reports for it and placed those reports in a single report.